# Calculating ELBO in EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, t-distribution

In [Andrew Ng's CS229 notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020spring/cs229-notes8.pdf), a nice derivation of EM algorithm is given. With some minor notation modifications, the algorithm is written as follows:

E-step: For each i, $Q_i(z_i)=p(z_i|x_i, \theta^{old})$

M-step: $\theta=arg\max_\theta\sum_{i=1}^N\textrm{ELBO}(x_i;Q_i,\theta)\\=arg\max_\theta\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{z_i}Q_i(z_i)\log\frac{p(x_i|z_i,\theta)p(z_i|\theta)}{Q_i(z_i)}$

where $z_i$ are the latent and $x_i$ are the observed variables.

We know that $p(z_i|x_i,\theta) \propto p(x_i,z_i|\theta)$. If $p(z_i|\theta)$ is conjugate for $p(x_i|z_i,\theta)$, we get $p(z_i|x_i,\theta)\propto p(z_i|\theta)$ as well.

In my case this caused all the $z_i$ terms in the expectation to vanish, and I couldn't figure out why.

Specifically, for Student's t distribution, $p(z_i|\theta)=\textrm{Gamma}(z_i|\nu/2,\nu/2)$ and we choose $Q_i(z_i) =  \textrm{Gamma}(z_i|a_i,b_i)$ because of proportionalities. All the terms that we calculate the expectation of cancels each other. In other words, for all $E[z_i]$ and $E[\log z_i]$ terms in the numerator inside $\log$, we have another one in the denominator. What am I doing wrong? Should I just ingore the denominator in $\log$?

**UPDATE:** Probably my confusion is because of the old and new parameters. Since $Q_i(z_i)$ depends on $\theta^{old}$, I think I should think it is constant and its derivative is zero, so I should drop it. However, I'm still not sure if it is correct and how to explain it correctly.

-- Question ends here. Please see below if you need to check out my derivations. --

---

$p(x_i|\theta)=\int_{z_i}N(x_i|\mu,(\lambda z_i)^{-1})Ga(z_i|\nu/2,\nu/2)$

$p(x_i,z_i|\theta)=N(x_i|\mu,(\lambda z_i)^{-1})Ga(z_i|\nu/2,\nu/2)$

$p(z_i|x_i,\theta) \propto p(x_i,z_i|\theta)$

Since Gamma is conjugate to normal distribution, $p(z_i|x_i, \theta)\propto p(z_i|\theta)$, so $p(z_i|x_i, \theta)=Ga(z_i|a_i,b_i)$.

By ignoring normalization terms, we get $a_i=\frac{\nu+1}{2}$ and $b_i=\frac{\lambda (x_i-\mu)^2+\nu}{2}$.

In the M-step, we solve the following:

$\theta=arg\max_\theta\sum_{i=1}^N \int_{z_i} Ga(z_i|a_i,b_i)\log\frac{N(x_i|\mu,(\lambda z_i)^{-1})Ga(z_i|\nu/2,\nu/2)}{Ga(z_i|a_i,b_i)}\\=arg\max_\theta\sum_{i=1}^N\int_{z_i}Ga(z_i|a_i,b_i)\left[-\frac{1}{2}\log2\pi+\frac{1}{2}\log\lambda +\frac{1}{2}\log z_i -\frac{1}{2} \lambda z_i (x_i-\mu)^2 -\log \Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})+\frac{\nu}{2}\log\frac{\nu}{2} + (\frac{\nu}{2}-1)\log z_i - \frac{\nu}{2}z_i +\log \Gamma(a_i) - a_i \log b_i - (a_i-1)\log z_i + b_i z_i\right]\\=arg\max_\theta\left[-\frac{N}{2}\log2\pi+\frac{N}{2}\log\lambda -N\log \Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})+N\frac{\nu}{2}\log\frac{\nu}{2} + N\log \Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2}) - N\frac{\nu+1}{2} \log \frac{\lambda(x_i-\mu)^2+\nu}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^N\int_{z_i}Ga(z_i|\frac{\nu+1}{2}, \frac{\lambda(x_i-\mu)^2+\nu}{2})\left[\color{red}{z_i \left(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda(x_i-\mu)^2-\frac{\nu}{2}+\frac{\lambda(x_i-\mu)^2+\nu}{2}\right)}\\+\color{blue}{
\log z_i \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\nu}{2}-1-\frac{\nu+1}{2}+1 \right)}\right]\right]$